# How to rename a directory under Mac (10.6.4) via the superuser?

Tags: mac, terminal, sudo, nfs

This is my directory list on my NFS:

> macbook-pro-andrey-k:Download Andrey$
>   ls
>   1289816143_PL_t1181913
>   1289816171_PL_t1183807
>   1290117075_BFD_DVD02(Drums)

I can't delete "1290117075_BFD_DVD02(Drums)" using

> sudo rm -Rf
>   1290117075_BFD_DVD02(Drums)

because I get the error message

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected
>   token `('

How can I either rename the directory so that the error message would not show up, or delete the directory right away omitting the renaming procedure?

Comment: The funniest thing is, you could have typed "sudo rm -Rf 129[tab]" and it would have been escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams says, you can surround the file name in quotes to have it treated as a literal. You can also escape characters with special meanings in the shell (space is probably the most common; you have just discovered brackets) with `\`, so your command would end up as:

```
sudo rm -Rf 1290117075_BFD_DVD02\(Drums\)
```

The escape character causes the character immediately after it (and no other) to be treated as a normal character.

Comment: And if dir name contains spaces and &-sign (i.e. 123_Pics & Video)

Comment: Just escape them all, one at a time. `123_Pics\ \&\ Video`. The backslash-and-something is what's known as a *digraph* - two characters that are interpreted as one. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo rm -Rf '1290117075_BFD_DVD02(Drums)'
```

Comment: And if dir name is for example 123_Pics & Video ?

Comment: @user56990: Single quotes will also work for that.